# Excel - add 6 months to a date then round to the nearest quarter

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

In an excel spreadsheet I have all of our employees hire dates listed, I need to add 6 months to this date, then have the result round to the nearest quarter showing the first date of the quarter not Q1, Q2, etc.

This is the formula I was building but it's not rounding to the first date of the quarter:

=DATE(YEAR(E2),MONTH(E2)+6+MOD(MONTH(E2),3),1)

Comment: What do you mean by round to nearest? What would 31-Mar-2018 count as?

Comment: It would be quarters based on a standard calendar year.  So if the date with six months added is 08/17/2018, it needs to then show the next quarter date of 10/01/2018.  The final results for the quarters should be one of these: 1/1/18, 4/1/18, 7/1/18, 10/1/18 or go into the next year if necessary.

Comment: So you always want to get the start date of the following quarter?

Comment: Try `=DATE(YEAR(E2),MONTH(E2)+6+CHOOSE(MOD(MONTH(E2),3)+1,1,3,2),1)`

Comment: That is perfect!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Phylogenesis please share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. | Alternatively, the question owner may do so too..  (:

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
=DATE(YEAR(E2),MONTH(E2)+6+CHOOSE(MOD(MONTH(E2),3)+1,1,3,2),1)
```

This uses the [`CHOOSE()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc) function to add 1-3 months depending on which month of the quarter the date falls on.